# laravel Redirect solution, where to put code which has to be executed with each request

Tags: laravel

in my app there is a row in a table that has to be filled before user can start to use the app. So he has to be redirected to 'create info page' from any place in the app. I tried to create a custom library for that so it redirects the user however it is acting weird when redirecting - so what is the best place to put the code which has to be executed with each request, global.php does not recognise the route I guess because it is called before the route.php

here is the code

```
if (MyinfoDB::find(1) == null && Route::currentRouteName() != 'get-myinfo-create') {
            return Redirect::route('get-myinfo-create')->with('fail', 'Your company information must be created before using the app');
        }
```

the ID is 1 because there has to be only one row in this table, its like settings for the app

Comment: You can create middleware to achieve this http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *probably* best place to put that sort of code is in a *middleware*.

> HTTP middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#introduction